# Jira Issue Detail View - Not showing fields

Tags: jira

In Jira when I click an issue from the kanban board, structure or from the issue search page it opens up the detailed view of the issue. It used to show all relevant information (description, fix versions, relates to etc.) Now it's only showing the structure part with agile board link and HipChat button on right hand side. Everything else is not showing up at all. This is happening on all projects.

Screenshot of what I mean: http://screencast.com/t/TBqPLVJnBc

What am I missing? I must have changed some setting but cant find anything anywhere. Also thought I would mention that clicking the edit button for the issue shows all fields and I can change description, versions, labels etc. They're just not showing in detail view.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Oldskoltxo for the help and ideas but in the end I have no idea what fixed this issue. I just logged back in today and it was working with the jiraurl/browse/issueid (detailed issue view) showing all the info that I wanted (and which as you can see from above screenshot it didnt show the other day). Eg Fix version, author, description, comments, applies to links etc. Everything is back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like when you installed the plugin for kanban, you accepted to set your view screen to a different one. Try editting that setting on Admin>issues>screens. And check what is shown on "View Screen" and what screen is shown for "edit issue".

Regards

Comment: Thanks but the screens don't show a 'view screen' and the 'default screen' shows all the fields there as you would expect. There is also lots of screen schemes which show all field tabs selected.

Comment: Ok, so first go to screen schemes and check wich one is being used by your workflow. when you know that, you can set your default view, or even better create your custom view, edit ... screens.

Comment: Ok yeah I see what you're saying and I added edit and view screens and like the default screen it shows all fields selected but I'm still seeing nothing when i open an issue. In the kanban board sidebar that shows a snapshot of an issue when I click it I can see all the fields but as soon as I click the issue-key link to open it full screen i get the view in my link.

Comment: It does say 'Note: when the screen is shown to the user only non-hidden fields that the user has permissions to edit will be actually displayed.' at the top of the screen scheme so maybe that is something to do with it. They're all enabled but all hidden?! But according to field configurations page they all look un-hidden

Comment: Have you set your current workflow to your new screen schemes? have you add the screen to the screen scheme? When you create a new screen scheme, you have to set there wich screen to use, for view, edit and create a issue. Then on field configuration scheme, for each field you should check that the fields  have set up the correct screen. If those steps are ok, you should have no problems

Comment: Ok so I gave up on this after getting nowhere and came back today to have another go and its working! All the info is back in the detailed view! So no idea what or how it is fixed but going to mark your answer as correct anyway as I think you've covered most of the possible reasons here. To anyone else with the same problem reading this, sorry but I've got nothing other than the above. I did not even update anything? Weird. Thanks again Oldskultxo!